# How to get format "00:34" for duration less than hour moment.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I have duration like:

```
{
_isValid: true
_milliseconds: 2040000
_days: 0
_months: 0
_data: {milliseconds: 0, seconds: 0, minutes: 31, hours: 3, days: 0, …}
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, …}
__proto__: Object
}
```

if I make duration.format("HH:mm") I get "34", how can I get "00:34"?

My code where I use this:

```
duration: timeEntries
            .slice(1)
            .reduce((prev, cur) => {
              return prev.add(cur.duration);
            }, moment.duration(timeEntries[0].duration))
            .format("HH:mm")
```

and my duration is 34, instead of 00:34, because duration is less than hour, in other cases, where time is bigger, it return a 1:30 for example

Comment: Can you create a sample code so we know what you have tried and what the mistake is?

Comment: @Rajesh sure, sry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Duration object has **_data** which contains the time object we need for formatting.

```js
//moment(moment.duration(duration_value)._data).format("HH:mm");
console.log(moment(moment.duration(3500000)._data).format("HH:mm"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```